# Can mobs spawn on upside-down stairs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a bridge through the Nether, out of Nether Brick. The only issue, is that the bridge enters the bounds of a Nether Fort, meaning that Blazes, and Wither Skeletons can spawn on it.

I know that they cannot spawn on right-side up stairs, and half slabs, if placed on the ground (half a block below the normal block height). This is due to the block not considered as being a "full" block.

However, if I place stairs upside down, will this still be the case?

Comment: I recommend the series "will it spawn" (sometimes included in "mythbusting") by Xisuma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobs can spawn on top of upside down stairs.  The top of the block is solid/full so it is counted.

[Here is the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Spawn_conditions) on the subject:

> the block directly below it must have a solid top surface (opaque, upside down slabs / stairs and others)

The wiki also states that for a blaze specifically:

> the light level must be 11 or darker

Comment: Yes.  I mentioned it because I have forgotten it a couple of times and had blaze surprise me.