# Can Creeper spawn on Netherrack in 1.20.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a Gunpowder farm and wanted to know if Creeper can spawn on Netherrack.

Comment: It's a normal, solid block.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318321/can-mobs-spawn-on-upside-down-stairs)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper#Spawning):

> Creepers naturally spawn in the Overworld on solid blocks with a light level of 0, except in mushroom fields and deep dark biomes.

So I don't see any problem with netherrack.